# Variable optimization with function

Tags: c#, optimization, global-variables, scope, benchmarking

Suppose I call `Print` very often in my code.

Do I have to declare `CurrentPosition` as global or local variable?

I want to know which version is faster.

**Option A:**

```
    int CurrentPosition = 0;
    void Print(string key, int conc, int col, byte _color) {
        if (col <= cMax ? col >= cMin : false) {
            if (CurrentRows.TryGetValue(key + "#" + conc.ToString(), out CurrentPosition)) { //Row is in the vieport
                grid.GetCell(CurrentPosition, col).Presenter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Option B:**

```
    void Print(string key, int conc, int col, byte _color) {
    int CurrentPosition = 0;
        if (col <= cMax ? col >= cMin : false) {
            if (CurrentRows.TryGetValue(key + "#" + conc.ToString(), out CurrentPosition)) { //Row is in the vieport
                grid.GetCell(CurrentPosition, col).Presenter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `col <= cMax ? col >= cMin : false` instead of `col <= cMax && col >= cMin`? The `&&` will short-circuit.

Comment: Why do you assign `=0` to the variable if it is passed as an `out` parameter? That `0` will be overwritten.

Comment: I think this is a small detail here. Anyway, the default value of the `int` type is zero. This is redundant in all cases, even without the `out` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to have a look under the hood to know how the C# compiler deals with these two options.

Let's say I have this simplistic class:

```
class Test
{
    private int _currentPosition;

    public int OptionA()
    {
        ImplOutParameter(out _currentPosition);
        return _currentPosition;
    }

    public int OptionB()
    {
        int currentPosition;
        ImplOutParameter(out currentPosition);

        return currentPosition;
    }

    public void ImplOutParameter(out int position)
    {
        position = 1;
    }
}
```

The two first methods are very similar to yours. The third one is here to test the `out` parameter implementation.

Let's compile this class in *Release* configuration. Using your favorite IL viewer, the method OptionA looks like:

[image: Method OptionA]

It pushes the reference of the object on the stack twice to get the variable member reference and to call the *ImplOutParameter* method. Then it returns the value of the variable member.

The method OptionB looks like:

[image: Method OptionB]

It pushes the reference of the object on the stack, pushes the address of the variable on the stack and call the *ImplOutParameter* method.Then it returns the value. It doesn't need to take time in order to allocate the variable.

Based on this analysis, I tend to say the OptionB implementation is a bit faster than the first one, but hey, this is very small. :)

Comment: (This comment goes beyond what the question asked.) At the same time, Option A is quite confusing to read because a variable that is only ever used locally inside one method is "promoted" to a class-level field. It also means that every instance of `Test` that resides in memory, will hold the field, even when the method is not called.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes you are right, this is a bit strange to read. Despite this, I assume this is the case of the OP. Of course, the OptionA is not a memory-saving optimized approach, but it was interesting to see if this approach was faster than the second one. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're maintaining the *state* of `CurrentPosition` between calls *and* you're not passing the value into the method, then it needs to be outside.  Otherwise, it starts fresh every time.

The *best* policy would be a third option of passing `CurrentPosition` into the method as a parameter, however, and maintain the state independent of the routine's code.

In terms of speed, allocation does take a small amount of time, but it's generally negligible. The "stack frame" will be lengthened regardless, and assigning a default value takes about as long as an assignment.

So, the most you'll save is a couple of cycles per call (i.e., nanonseconds), but yes, declaring it outside is going to be a hair faster.

Comment: I'am not maintaining the state of CurrentPosition. I want to know which version is faster.

Comment: Ah. In that case, there may be a tiny (but only tiny) edge to declaring outside. Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which is faster, test it. That's the only way to really be sure.

Always test performance if you're making a decision on what method to choose based on it. If it isn't worth testing, then you don't need the extra cycles.

That being said, the two methods are [i]functionally[/i] different, so your decision shouldn't be based on their speed. Option B sets CurrentPosition each time Print is called, whereas Option A sets CurrentPosition to 0 once and its value when Print is called is [i]not guaranteed to be 0[/i] so you should choose whichever option provides the correct function.

I can tell you that the speed different will likely be negligible, practically non-existent between the two.